# chrome extension multiple tabs and chrome.runtime.connect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am opening a long-lived connection with background from a content script if the url is test.com. I am using chrome.runtime.connect. But if I open multiple tabs with test.com, I am getting multiple onMessage calls from the background script.

The question is that the content scripts are not shared with multiple tabs but how come the ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design, since if you didn't call `runtime.Port.disconnect`, the previous connection will be maintained and every time you open a new tab with `test.com`, you content script is loaded and starts to establish another long-lived connection.

You could call `runtime.Port.disconnect` to cut the current connection when a new tab is created, or you may distinguish different connections by `Port`, you can access `port.MessageSender` on `runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){});`, which contains `tab` as unique info for the sender.

Comment: Ah, so it is not content script thing, it is port connection. So if I have 2 tabs open and 2 port connections, any request from background to each port will be twice. So each tab will receive 2 requests, correct?

Comment: @pvnarula, exactly, as long as the connection is not terminated.

Comment: @pvnarula, NP, and if my answer has helped, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. Thanks for recalling me. Thanks again for your help.